# Triangle created from point reflection over original, smaller triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am helping my young nephew with his math homework. There is a problem which I was unable to solve, despite having several college math courses finished. This is the problem:

There is a right angled triangle $ABC$. It has its right angle at the point $C$. By using point reflection, we create

- point $A'$ by reflecting $A$ over C
- point $B'$ by reflecting B over A
- point $C'$ by reflecitng C over B

Knowing the lengths $|AB|, |BC|, |CA|$, calculate $|A'B'|^2, |B'C'|^2, |C'A'|^2$

No goniometric functions are allowed. Just pure Pythagoras' theorem and basic triangle identities about its height, altitudes, orthocentres, etc.

I was able to solve the length $|C'A'|^2 = 4|CB|^2+|AC|^2$. I was unable to solve for the other two. How would one go about solving them?

EDIT: $ABC$ is not necessarily an isosceles triangle.

[image]

Comment: Reflect $B$ about $C$ to $B''$ and join $B'B''$ to create two other right angled triangles.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca thank you, you can upload your comment as an answer as it allowed me to finish the problem. I will accept it as an answer